# How can this while loop be broken?

Tags: matlab

```
counter = [2 3 3 4 5];
while counter(1:5)~=zeros(1,5)
    counter(1)=0;
end
counter
```

I know this is a stupid code but I don't understand as to how this while loop gets broken. I want a loop to exist until all the counters become 0 i.e.)counter=[0 0 0 0 0] not just one of them.

Can someone tell why this loop gets broken and write while loop that has my original intention?

Comment: [Docs](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/while.html#bub68r8-11): "If the conditional expression evaluates to a matrix, MATLAB evaluates the statements only if all elements in the matrix are true (nonzero). To execute statements if any element is true, wrap the expression in the `any` function."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line

```
counter(1) = 0;
```

is one problem. You only ever change that one element of `counter`. You need to add some sort of code to your loop that is capable of setting any/all of the elements of `counter` to zero or you can end up with an infinite loop.

In addition, you need to change `counter(1:5)~=zeros(1,5)` to `any(counter(1:5)~=zeros(1,5))` as TroyHaskin already commented, so that it will keep running until all elements of `counter` are zero.